# iPhone: Multiple touches on a UIButton are not recognized

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, touchesbegan, touches

I have a UIButton (a subclass of one, actually) that interacts with the user via the touchesbegan: and touchesmoved: functions.

What I would like is for the user to be able to press down the button, drag their finger away, and have a second finger touch the button (all while the first finger has never left the screen).

Problem is, the second touch event never calls touchesbegan: unless the first finger has been released.

Is there some way to override this, or am I trying to do the impossible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried setting `multipleTouchesEnabled` to YES?

Comment: Ah how silly of me, I thought I had tried this but obviously not. Cheers :)

Comment: thanks it solved my problem of multiple touches i wanted to make app handle single touch.

Answer (score 0):

If the interactions are using  `touchesbegan:` and `touchesmoved:` then use a UIView instead of a `UIButton`. A button is a UIControl, and the way to interact with UIControls is

```
- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents.
```

I'm not sure this two ways of getting events mix well.

Comment: Bit of a toss up... I am using a UIButton because of the setBackgroundImage:forState: method. It's working now, so I guess a UIButton will do in this case. Thanks though!